# Deploying exploded war jetty intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty, war

So I have 2 modules defined in intellij, one is a JAR and has the classes, one is a WAR and basically just has a hello world type page.  However after building the modules in my `/Users/nathan/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty`.. folder all I get to deploy is an empty jsp folder and none of my index.html or other stuff seems to get deployed.

Anyone have any suggestions.  I've been stuck for a couple hours and it's really frustrating.

If I look in the output folder I can see my `WEB-INF, META-INF` containing all the files I would expect to see...jetty just doesn't seem to be picking them up.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**
Ok, so it turns out it is working...at least in some way.  So I added the index.html file directly as you can see in the next screen shot, and now when the application start up I can properly navigate to my index.html and I get the page.  The /temp/jetty...file still shows just an empty jsp folder so I assume it's normal to have an empty folder there when deploying an exploded WAR?  Can someone confirm or rebut that?  Also the rest of my application seems to be there because my remote calls into the service are also working (in addition to the index.html).  So I'm off and happy except that I'm still not clear on how it could be better configured so I don't have to specify the index.html file specifically -- after all it is already in the webapp/WEB-INF folder and so should be available.

[image]

Comment: Jetty 8.x is EOL (End of Life).  Consider upgrading.  (you'll get more people interested in your question too, as it becomes more relevant)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with JDK 1.6 which prohibits me going to a later version of jetty.